# Batch Command to Cygwin after Cygwin Loads

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, cygwin, directory

I would like to load up my Cygwin shell into bash but immediately upon loading I want it to change into a particular directory.  The reason for this is so that I can have multiple batches to run to get into particular directories upon first load of cygwin without having to type cd  each time I load up.  I have multiple places I want to load up into, so you might see why having multiple batch files would be usefull.

So far I have this in my demo_app.bat file...

```
@echo off
start mintty -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico - 
"cd /cygdrive/c/cygwin/home/Alex/rails_projects/demo_app/"
```

But a cygwin window just pops up into my home directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution I was looking for.

This allows me to write multiple batch files in my toolbar that I can just click and then jump right into the particular directory that it happens to include, while in my profile bash...

```
start mintty /bin/env CHERE_INVOKING=1 /bin/bash --login -i -c 'cd /cygdrive/c/cygwin/home/Alex/rails_projects/demo_app/; exec bash'
```

Thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: Similarly if I want to go to another directory, I just write a separate script that allows for it to start there... I just change the 'cd /cygdrive...' part

Answer (score 2):

try this:

The command name is `cd` and **must not** be in double quotes.
For details please look at [anishsane's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17398482/2098699) posting :)

Comment: Unless mintty exits, it will not execute the further command. This solution will not work.

Comment: Err.. this will not work either. Batch does not know `/cygdrive/c`.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
@echo off
cd C:\cygwin\home\Alex\rails_projects\demo_app
start mintty -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico
```

NOTE: This will start with your shell in the correct directory, but it will not load your default environment.

Note: `-` is missing from the end of `mintty` command line.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're using `bash`, appending the following line to your `${HOME}/.bashrc` would achieve the desired result:

```
cd /cygdrive/c/cygwin/home/Alex/rails_projects/demo_app/
```

Comment: but I'm going to have multiple batch files going to different directories so I don't want to just have the one static place for my bash to start out into